# Ruby on Rails, Simple Form, Send multiple values of variable (i.e. different rows)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, simple-form

This should be simple to do, but I can't seem to find any documentation for it.  I am using Rails 3.2 and simple_form.  I want to make a form where a user can submit multiple rows of data at once.  For example, the form will be:

Animal type: ***_*_**  Name: ***_*____**

I want them to be able submit multiple rows.  So they can do:

```
Animal type:  Dog    Name: Fido
Animal type:  Dog    Name: Charley
Animal type:  Cat    Name: Logan
```

etc.

The goal is to be able to submit as many items as the user has, with new input rows being created through javascript.  I just don't know how the code is written for the form submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to do something with javascript. Here's some code for a jQuery implementation of a similar feature (only for 1 field, you need to adjust accordingly for two):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('#linkToClick').click(function() {
   var id_count = document.getElementById('id_count');
   var newIndex = parseInt(id_count);
   var html = '<input type="text" name="type[' + newIndex + '] size=15 />';
   jQuery('#idOfWhereToAdd').before(html);
   id_count.value = newIndex + 1;
   return false;
   }) 
});
```

This assumes you have a hidden input on your form, presumably with a value of 0 or 1 and an id of id_count. Also need an a tag (link) with an id of linkToClick.

Give that a try and let me know how it works.

Comment: If I understand right, on click that will check the current count of fields, add a new field with the field count (i.e. type1, type2, type3... ), and then increment the count.  That makes sense for adding the new fields.  What about the form though?  How does this get posted to the server, and how do I process that in rails?

Comment: Ah I understand now.  So I will have, for example, animal1 name1, animal2 name2, etc.  I just need to iterate through these and save them to the db.

Comment: Well, the above works in php. When the form is submitted, you have an array of 'type' which you can iterate through to get the values, and then save them wherever you need to. I'm not exactly sure how it will work in Ruby, but I assume pretty similarly. But yes, sounds like you have the idea!